# error: use of undeclared identifier 'vkFreeDescriptorSets' even though it is declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ndk-build

While using ndk-build to run the code on an emulator or smartphone I get the Error above even though the identifier is being declared in a different class (see code below).
Running it with visual studio on my PC I had no issues what so ever.

This is where the problem occurs:

```
class DescriptorSetList : public VulkanResourceList<VkDescriptorSet>
{
private:
    VkDescriptorPool descriptorPool;
public:
    DescriptorSetList(VkDevice &dev, VkDescriptorPool pool) : VulkanResourceList(dev), descriptorPool(pool) {};

    ~DescriptorSetList()
    {
        for (auto& descriptorSet : resources)
        {
            vkFreeDescriptorSets(device, descriptorPool, 1, &descriptorSet.second);
        }
    }

    VkDescriptorSet add(std::string name, VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocInfo)
    {
        VkDescriptorSet descriptorSet;
        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocInfo, &descriptorSet));
        resources[name] = descriptorSet;
        return descriptorSet;
    }
};
```

This is where the identifier is being declared:

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkFreeDescriptorSets(
    VkDevice                                    device,
    VkDescriptorPool                            descriptorPool,
    uint32_t                                    descriptorSetCount,
    const VkDescriptorSet*                      pDescriptorSets);
```

I have tried different methods, which I have found on here, of declaring and calling the identifier, but nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you `#include`d the file which declares that function?

Comment: Yes of course! I even double checked the spelling.